# Here Maps Tap Listener to show info bubble in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, here-api, heremaps

I'm trying to add a **tap listener** to my map markers on my map to show an **info-bubble** to show details about that location in my **Flutter** app. I tried to use the **Here Maps **Map Pin**** option but I can't seem to combine on-tap gestures with creating a widget pin. I saw that the JavaScript SDK has a function to add info-bubble to map markers. Is there a way to do that in Flutter apart from the Map Pins?

This is a for loop I wrote to go through the list of Map markers on the map to create the Widget pin for each of them :

```
     for (var a = 0; a < _mapMarkerList.length; a++) {
          _hereMapController.gestures.tapListener =
              TapListener((Point2D touchPoint) {
            _hereMapController.viewToGeoCoordinates(touchPoint);
            _hereMapController.pinWidget(
                _createWidget('Here is my label', Color(0xFFFCAE06)),
                _mapMarkerList.elementAt(a).coordinates);
          });
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not create a tap listener multiple times for each marker. Instead create only one tap listener. And then pick a marker with `_hereMapController.pickMapItems()`. Inside the callback you can create a map view pin.

```
  void _setTapGestureHandler() {
    _hereMapController.gestures.tapListener = TapListener((Point2D touchPoint) {
      _pickMapMarker(touchPoint);
    });
  }

  void _pickMapMarker(Point2D touchPoint) {
    double radiusInPixel = 2;
    _hereMapController.pickMapItems(touchPoint, radiusInPixel, (pickMapItemsResult) {
      if (pickMapItemsResult == null) {
        // Pick operation failed.
        return;
      }    

      List<MapMarker> mapMarkerList = pickMapItemsResult.markers;
      int listLength = mapMarkerList.length;
      if (listLength == 0) {
        print("No map markers found.");
        return;
      }

      MapMarker topmostMapMarker = mapMarkerList.first;
      // Now create a map view pin based on this marker's coordinates.
    });
  }
```

See this example app for more context: https://github.com/heremaps/here-sdk-examples/blob/d07e4af93b2db946a1f97fdc12cfd6f4b0a760fc/examples/latest/navigate/flutter/map_items_app/lib/MapItemsExample.dart#L306

Comment: Thank you very much for responding. I implemented your suggestion. I added the create pin method and used the coordinates from the "topmostMapMarker". But I get an error when I tap the markers on the map : [ERROR] geoviz-map2d - Unexpected index ranges. Do you have any idea why that is so? –

Comment: It works now, I was calling my pin widget wrongly. The correct way is : "_hereMapController.pinWidget(
          yourPinWidget,
          topmostMapMarker.coordinates); ". Thanks a lot, @Nusatad! The documentation was super helpful as well.